# SQL Where to exclude range using two variables

Tags: sql, range, coordinates, where-clause, between

I am trying to create a WHERE statement, where excludes a square of coordinates.

I have saved on a table some records with its X and Y coordinates.

I want to exclude the records that are between x1 and x2 and y1 and y1

I was using

```
select * from dbo.records where (x not between x1 and x2)  and  (y not between y1 and y2)
```

but the first not between is deleting me a lot of coordinates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xeojj.png)

Do you know a way to get the ordinates inside the square?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want `or`ed conditions:

```
 where (x not between x1 and x2) or (y not between y1 and y2)
```

I find that it is clearer to phrase this as:

```
 where not (x between x1 and x2 and y between y1 and y2)
```

Conditions `x between x1 and x2 and y between y1 and y2` define coordinates that belong to the square; you want coordinates that do not satisfy these conditions.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you!. I have never seen that not.